# How do you define node_modules as externs in Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-closure-compiler

I have a Node.js project that I want to compile with Closure Compiler. I do not want it to run in the browser/use browserify. I mainly want the utility of type checking. I originally got the compiler to work correctly using the following:

```
java -jar compiler.jar -W VERBOSE 
                       --language_in ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT 
                       --externs closure-externs.js 
                       --js="lib/**.js"
```

Where `closure-externs.js` manually defined variables and functions which I was using from Node.js in a rather crude way:

```
// closure-externs.js

/** @constructor */function Buffer(something){}
function require(path){}
var process = {};
[...]
```

It turns out that this worked only through sheer luck. There is no dependency tracking between files, so you can have cases where you return a type `{Foo}` and the compiler will complain that it doesn't exist (depending on the machine, depending on the compile order). I then found out I was doing it all wrong and should be using `--process_common_js_modules` so the compiler will do dependency tracking where I `require("foo")`. I am currently invoking the compiler like so:

```
java -jar compiler.jar -W VERBOSE 
                       --language_in ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT 
                       --externs externs/fs.js 
                       --js="lib/**.js"
                       --process_common_js_modules 
                       --common_js_entry_module app.js
```

But this is failing with:

```
 ERROR - required entry point "module$crypto" never provided
 ERROR - required entry point "module$dgram" never provided
 ERROR - required entry point "module$extend" never provided
 ERROR - required entry point "module$fs" never provided
 ERROR - required entry point "module$net" never provided
 ERROR - required entry point "module$q" never provided
```

Some of these modules are native to Node.js (e.g. `fs`) whereas others are contained in `node_modules` like `q`. I don't want to run these external modules through the compiler, so I know I need to set up `externs` file(s) for them. I know there is https://github.com/dcodeIO/node.js-closure-compiler-externs for common Node.js externs, and I know how to invoke them on the compiler, but for some reason when I do something like `--externs externs/fs.js` the error for `module$fs` remains. What am I doing wrong?

I know there's other flags like `--module` and `--common_js_module_path_prefix` but I'm not sure if I need to use them to get this to work or not. My Google-fu has failed to come up with any answers on the correct incantation here. :(

Comment: Many of the externs you need are officially maintained in the compiler project: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/tree/master/contrib/nodejs. The contrib externs are now also distributed as part of the official npm package for the compiler: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-closure-compiler

Comment: I know these files exist. My question is how do I use these files correctly with ``compiler.jar`` as ``--externs`` doesn't seem to be working as I think it should.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment - I'm interested in an answer as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you wish for the compiler to somehow recognize that certain `require` calls are internal, namely that the required module should be processed by the compiler as source, and others are external so should be left alone. There isn't a good way to handle this situation currently.

## Workarounds

### Use Post-processing to Add External Require Statements

In this scenario you would completely omit any `require` statements to external modules. The compiler would only process code with internal require statements and modules. After compilation, you would prepend the external require statements:

#### Header JS To Be Prepended

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
```

#### Source To Be Compiled

```
console.log(crypto);
```

Because `crypto` is declared in an extern, the compiler will correctly recognize the type and symbol name.

### Alias Require Calls

When the `--process_common_js_modules` is specified, the compiler recognizes `require` statements and expands them in a similar fashion to the way macros work in other languages. By aliasing the `require` statements that should remain external, the compiler will not recognize them and thus not expand them.

#### Source To Be Compiled

```
var externalRequire = require;
/** @suppress {duplicate} this is already defined in externs */
var crypto = externalRequire('crypto');
console.log(crypto)
```

Comment: Thanks Chad, this addresses the question and provides a decent solution for anyone wanting to get this to work in the future. Related back-and-forth: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/954

Comment: Using any of these workarounds throws "WARNING - name module is not defined in the externs." because on each official externs file for Node.js that defines a module ("path" for example) exports the public definitions using "module.exports = path;". Why fails if i add the "process_common_js_modules" to compiler flags?

Comment: The official externs seem to require a custom runner - which is not part of the official repo. Our nodejs support right now just isn't where we'd like it to be. It's being worked on, but it's a slow process. If you remove the `module.exports` line in the nodejs externs, the workarounds here should start functioning.

Comment: I would be happy to see a working example of this answer, its not really clear to me

Comment: These work great for my source code, but unfortunate do not solve the problem of npms which in turn require built-in modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Closure Compiler *only* for type-checking—i.e., with the `--checks-only` option—there is another workaround which has the advantage (over the ones mentioned in [Chad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30350032/4969945)) of working correctly with unmodified third-party NPM modules which in turn import built-in modules.

## Using Stubs

The trick is to create stub NPM modules to stand in for the built-in ones.  These can be minimal; they only need to declare the parts of the API you're actually using.

Here's an example for the `path` built-in module.

In `externs/path/path.js` I have the "externs" declarations (not actually externs, so e.g. you can't use @nosideeffects) for the part of `path` that I need:

```
/** @const */
var path = {};

/**
 * @param {string} path
 * @return {string}
 */
path.dirname = function(path) {};

/**
 * @param {string} path
 * @return {string}
 */
path.extname = function(path) {};

/**
 * @param {...string} var_args
 * @return {string}
 */
path.join = function(var_args) {};

module.exports = path;
```

In `externs/path/package.json`, I have a minimal NPM package config:

```
{
  "description": "Fake package.json for require('path')",
  "main": "path.js",
  "name": "path",
}
```

Then create a symlink from `node_modules/path` to `externs/path`, and add the following to my compiler flags:

```
node_modules/path/package.json
node_modules/path/path.js
```

(You could put the stub implementation directly in to `node_modules` but I prefer to keep my stubs separate from the real modules managed by `npm`.  I just need to remember to manually add the symlinks to my Git repo, because it's otherwise configured to ignore `node_modules`.)