# New Closure Compiler module support and externs for Node.js buildin modules

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

As far as i know the newest Closure Compiler supports three types of modules: ES6, CommonJS and goog.module(). How can i use the Nodejs internal modules?

I have this very simple code:

```
const path = require('path');
```

And this compiler flags, among others:

```
--dependency_mode STRICT
--env CUSTOM (without this fails as well)
--externs nodejs/path.js
--language_in ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT
--language_out ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT
--new_type_inf
--process_common_js_modules
--use_types_for_optimization
```

And the compiler throws:

```
ERROR - Failed to load module "path"
```

Any hints?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you define node\_modules as externs in Closure Compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261330/how-do-you-define-node-modules-as-externs-in-closure-compiler)

Comment: when i not use the "require" function i got "name module is not defined in the externs"